How to send on/off commands to Dell projector using TCP server to RS232 port
I have a Dell 7700 projector that has both a webpage control, and a serial port RS232. I have tried to no avail to find a specific line of code that would allow me to send an on/off command via http (I am able to do it with the Eiki projector).
My goal is to control it using an Elgato Stream Deck to turn it on and off. Since a simple http send command won't work, I found a Bitfocus Companion app that works as a server to either send ASCII code or Hex commands. So, I recently purchased a USR TCp232-410s device which can act as a serial server over a network. I have successfully connected to the IP address of this device, and I have set the correct baud rate and port so I am now getting feedback from the projector. However, I am stuck as far as the commands to send because it is not working.
Here is some info from the manual:
Control Command Syntax (From PC to Projector)
[H][AC][SoP][CRC][ID][SoM][COMMAND]
[H][AC][SoP][CRC][ID][SoM][COMMAND][Value]
Example: Power On Command (Send Low Byte Firstly)
Enter the following code:
0xbe, 0xef, 0x10, 0x05, 0x00, 0xc6, 0xff, 0x11, 0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01

Header [H] ==> Fixed, “be (Low Byte), ef (High Byte)”
Address Code [AC] ==> Fixed, “10”
Size of Payload [SoP] ==> Byte size from MsgID to Command Code, “05 (Low
Byte), 00 (High Byte)” or Byte size from MsgID to Value, “06 (Low Byte), 00
(High Byte)”.
CRC16 [CRC] ==> CRC value, “c6 (Low Byte), ff (High Byte)”
MsgID [ID] ==> Fixed, “11 11”
MsgSize [SoM] ==> Byte size of Command Code, “01 (Low Byte), 00 (High
Byte)” or Byte size of Command Code and Value, “02 (Low Byte), 00 (High Byte)”
Command Code [COMMAND] ==> “Power On” Command, “01”

In the Control Commands list, it also shows this:
Here is the link to the PDF of the RS232 commands: [https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_projector/dell-7700hd_reference%20guide_en-us.pdf](Dell Manual)
So, since I am a tinkerer and not a programmer, any help would be appreciated!
What I have tried:

sending ASCII commands like Power On or 001.
sending Hex commands like 0xbe, 0xef, 0x10, 0x05, 0x00, 0xc6, 0xff, 0x11, 0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01
Sending Hex over the ASCII and vice versa.
taking out the 0x and just sending be ef 10 05....

Nothing happened - it neither powered on or off. I tried all the possible endings and no endings even though it seems like it /lf should be the correct ending. The bitfocus companion app gives options for sending to a serial port for things like a common Unix ending, a common Windows ending, a common 70s terminal ending, etc.

"What I have tried: ..." - Your word descriptions convey no information at all. "Send" how? It's rare for a user method to send data (e.g. a terminal emulation program) that allows a binary-mode for data entry. If you're using Linux, then you have a chance of success with a terminal emulation program like miinicom (that can send a raw file) and a binary editor like hexedit.

The program is in the Bitfocus Companion project and it is called tcp-udp.  Here is their definition of what it does:The companion project is designed to make the everyday life of a technician easier. We pefer to have ready made actions, presets and feedbacks for as many products as possible.
This generic TCP/UDP module is intended for testing or small-scale products.                             It connects to the USR device via ip address and target port, and I am seeing that it receives the data, plus it is returning some type of hex feedback, but it is not performing any actions on project

You could possibly see what you're doing wrong by taking the serial connection to the PJ, and instead route it back to a (USB?) serial port on a PC. Use a terminal emulation program like miinicom that can display received data (which is actually what you're trying to send to the PJ) as either text or in hexadecimal representation. If you can't make sense of the hex data displayed, then you're sending it incorrectly as text. BTW any "options for sending ... things like a common Unix ending ..." means that you're in text-sending mode, rather than sending the intended binary values.
